# What is causing this redirect_to to fail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, redirecttoaction

I am trying to use this redirect_to

```
redirect_to :controller => :note_categories, :action => :destroy, :note_id => params[:id]
```

This is the URL that results

```
http://localhost:3000/note_categories/272?note_id=272
```

and this is the error message

```
Unknown action
No action responded to show. Actions: destroy
```

The reason I am redirecting to the note_categories destroy action, and passing in the note id, is that in the destroy action, I am finding all the note_categories related to note, running some code on them, then destroying them. I know this isn't a great way to be doing this, but I couldn't use :dependant => :destroy because the code I have to run on the note_category before I delete it needs access to current_user, which can't happen in the note_category model.

So yeah, can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong in my redirect_to? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `redirect_to` method is essentially the Rails implementation of the [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) (PRG) web design pattern. It's used to prevent duplicate form submissions caused by the user clicking the browser's Refresh button after submitting a form.

The typical Rails usage is like this for creating an object:

- A form for creating an object is displayed (`new` action/HTTP GET)
- The user fills in the form
- The form is submitted (`create` action/HTTP POST)
- The object is created and saved
- A `redirect_to` is performed with an HTTP 301/302 status to the object's `show` view or perhaps `index`

—for editing an object it's:

- A form for edit an existing object is displayed (`edit` action/HTTP GET)
- The user fills in the form
- The form is submitted (`update` action/HTTP PUT)
- The object is updated and saved
- A `redirect_to` is performed with an HTTP 301/302 status to the object's `show` view or perhaps `index`

You can't redirect directly to the `destroy` action because in RESTful Rails that's intended to be invoked as a result of an HTTP DELETE request and doesn't render a template when it's invoked. The `redirect_to` method always redirects to a template.

You haven't shown us the code for destroying notes, but I suspect that what you're trying to achieve can be done with a before filter and by having the controller passing the current user to a model method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That clears things up about redirect_to for me. Just wondering, could you please explain your last paragraph? Do you mean that I should be calling a method in the NoteCategory model from the destroy action of the Note controller, passing it current_user?

Comment: @ben Possibly, you'd have to post your controller and model code. Perhaps as a separate question...